# Rails upgrade broke custom domains on dev server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, url-routing

I just upgraded my Rails app from 4.1.3 to 4.2.4.  I had previously edited my development server's host file so that `my.domain` pointed to localhost and had been using this to work on my app.  However, now that I've upgraded to rails 4.2.4, `my.domain:3000` doesn't connect; only `localhost:3000` does.

I can't remember if I originally configured anything else that would have been affected by the upgrade but I don't think I did. There's nothing in the `development.log` that would give any hints (makes sense given that the browser says it's not even connecting).

In the event that it matters, I'm using `gem 'foreman', '~> 0.78.0'` on my dev server.

I know I'm not giving a lot to work with but does anyone have any ideas as to what might be going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This probably has to do with [Rails 4.2 no longer binding to the public interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_2_release_notes.html#default-host-for-rails-server). I'm not sure if your dev server is local or not. If it is, you will probably need to adjust your hosts entry to 127.0.0.1 instead of 0.0.0.0. If not, you will probably need to allow Rails to use the public interface. There is a [bug report for this issue](https://github.com/samuelkadolph/unicorn-rails/issues/12), which contains some possible workarounds.

Comment: I thought this would be the problem but didn't know the right terminology explain it. Nicely done.

Comment: Thanks, @sevenseacat!

Answer (score 0):

Due to a change in Rack, rails server now listens on localhost instead of 0.0.0.0 by default. Refer [4.2 release notes](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_2_release_notes.html#default-host-for-rails-server) Start your server with :

```
rails server -b 0.0.0.0
```

to restore old behaviour

Comment: @neanderslob, for what it's worth, you should try to get it working on 127.0.0.1. The reason it changed is because it is more secure that way. Also, starting with additional unnecessary arguments is not a good long term plan.

Comment: @BradWerth upon reexamining my host file, I found that I was using 127.0.1.1 (I missed that extra 1 when I looked at it initially).  I changed that to 127.0.0.1 and, just as you said, no problem.  Many thanks for the explanation.